# In the DCAU continuity, when did Superman go rogue?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-animated-universe, justice-league-unlimited

In the Justice League Unlimited episode 6 of season 1, titled Fearful Symmetry, when they reference that Superman went rogue before, when did this take place? Was it ever on screen?

I've been rewatching the Justice League series on HBOMax so I'm not sure if it's in another series like Superman:TAS or Batman: TAS.

Answer (score 6):

It happened in the [two parts episode named Legacy](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Legacy) of [Superman: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman%3A_The_Animated_Series), which as you know happens in the same continuity as the Justice League Unlimited albeit before.

In that episode...

> Superman was captured by Darkseid and brainwashed into believing he was raised on Apokolips instead of Earth. Eventually, Darkseid sent him to conquer Earth. If he succeeds, Darkseid wins, and if not, he tarnished Superman's reputation among the Earthlings.

You'll find an excerpt of that episode [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRtuBIcPpms) (embedded video was disabled by author).